# Android: How to remove the spacing after the "1" digit in a TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

Here is a screen shot of the background of a few `TextViews` all with same attributes set, except for the text:

[image]

As you can see, the last three `TextViews` wrap the content perfectly fine, but for the first `TextView` there is some spacing after the "1," and it's throwing off the centering of the text within it. Anybody know of a way to remove the spacing after the "1"?

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: for the time being you can use negative right padding with "Example 1" TextView as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
if(tvExample.getText().toString().endsWith("1")){
            tvExample.setPadding(0, 0, -5, 0);
        }
```